# Parse Exception in javax.mail MimeMessage

Tags: java, parsing, mime-message

I have found my very same error in

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2449918

According to the answer, the email is just wrong. My question is, is there any idea about how to handle the problem?
As in the question says, if I try to send:

> Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers;
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Instead of

> Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers; Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

It will work.

By using the property [mail.mime.contenttypehandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) I could add my own class to clean up the Content-Type header, but it might be risky, since a complete validation, regex... etc could bring more problems than it solves. 
Has anybody faced this problem before? How would it be soved?

Any idea would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html), the problem is the Content-Type parameter structure, ti should be:

```
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers; Content-Transfer-Encoding= 8bit
```

I have just created a class to fix it, but still I think there must be some better solution.
If someone finds it, please keep answering! :)

Thanks

```
public static String cleanContentType(String contentType){
        StringBuilder cleanedContentType = new StringBuilder();
        if(contentType.contains(";")){   //It contains paramenter
            cleanedContentType.append(contentType.split(";")[0]).append("; ");
            if(contentType.split(";").length > 1){
                for(int i = 1; i < contentType.split(";").length ; i++){
                    cleanedContentType.append(contentType.split(";")[i].replace(":", "=")).append("; ");
                }
            }
        } else{
            return contentType;
        }

        return cleanedContentType.toString();
    }
```